# Sharepoint 2010 SPListTemplate how to get list of fields?

Tags: .net, api, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I need to get all fields from my list template?
How can i do this?

```
var web = site.OpenWeb();
var template = web.ListTemplates["SomeTemplate"];
template ... ???? -There is no method to get fields.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method to get all fields from a list template. The only way you can get the fields is by parsing the [Schema XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplate.schemaxml.aspx) of the list and getting all `<Field>` and `<FieldRef>` tags.

Easier is to create a list instance, which you can query later on with the following examples.

To get all fields from a list you can use the `SPList.Fields` Property, e.g. like so:

```
foreach (SPField spField in myList.Fields)
{
    //your code here
}
```

[MSDN SPListItem.Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.fields.aspx)

You can also get all fields from a list item "in reverse" `SPListItem.Fields` [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.fields.aspx). You might also be interested in this SO thread: [Check if a List Column Exists using SharePoint Client Object Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401253/check-if-a-list-column-exists-using-sharepoint-client-object-model)

Comment: This is so bad. Sharepoint disappointing me. I want programmatically update my list in site to match template.Becouse after redeployment of feature new fields not appear in lists. Maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot update existing list based on a new list definition. You can only update content types - see this post for more information: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0cd38a26-476b-459c-a5b2-15267e9b8f55